# How to get a column from a table that corresponds to another table

Tags: query, syntax

I have these tables:

OrderDetails:
[image]

Orders:
[image]

Employees:
[image]

Products:
[image]

Customers:
[image]

I want to write a query where I can get the last name of the employee with the largest order quantity. I managed to write these following queries:

```
'Selects biggest purchase from OrderDetails'
SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM [OrderDetails];

'Selects the OrderID of orders'
SELECT OrderID FROM [OrderDetails];

SELECT EmployeeID FROM [Orders]
SELECT OrderID FROM [Orders]
```

But I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: I know that my queries are incorrect. I just want to know how to write the correct queries for this.

Comment: Please tag your database system, implementation, and version, so that accurate answers can be provided.

Comment: Also, in genereal please provide create table and insert statements for a test case rather than images.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not sure whether you're looking for the person who sold the most of a thing on an individual order, or the person who sold the most of a thing over a period of time, here is a rough query that will allow you to see both:

```
SELECT e.LastName, tmp.MaxQuantity, tmp.SumQuantity
  FROM Employees e INNER JOIN (SELECT o.EmployeeID, MAX(od.Quantity) as MaxQuantity, SUM(od.Quantity) as SumQuantity
                                 FROM Orders o INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
                                GROUP BY o.EmployeeID) tmp ON e.EmployeeID = tmp.EmployeeID
 ORDER BY tmp.MaxQuantity DESC;
```

If you want to know who sold the most of a product on a single OrderDetail line, use `ORDER BY tmp.MaxQuantity DESC`. If you want to know who has sold the most of a product ever, use `ORDER BY tmp.`SumQuantity DESC`.

Be sure to edit this query to:

- limit the number of rows to something reasonable
- limit the date ranges to something reasonable (unless you really do want 25 years of data)
- take into account people who may no longer be in the `Employees` table if they have left the company

---

Edit to show a possible "filter by country" option:

If you are interested in filtering by country, or some other Customer attribute, you can add the `Customers` table to the subquery like so:

```
SELECT e.LastName, tmp.MaxQuantity, tmp.SumQuantity
  FROM Employees e INNER JOIN (SELECT o.EmployeeID, MAX(od.Quantity) as MaxQuantity, SUM(od.Quantity) as SumQuantity
                                 FROM Customers cu INNER JOIN Orders o ON cu.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                                                   INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
                                WHERE cu.CountryCode = 'DE'
                                GROUP BY o.EmployeeID) tmp ON e.EmployeeID = tmp.EmployeeID
 ORDER BY tmp.MaxQuantity DESC;
```

> **Note:** I do not know the structure of your `Customers` table, so be sure to edit this accordingly.

If your `Customers` table uses the full country name, you may want to double check that there are no "short forms" that create discrepancies in the data. A good example of this would be "United States of America", which could be written in full, or as "USA" or "U.S.A." or "US" or "U.S." and on and on and on. Depending on how your database is laid out, this could be a good opportunity to double-check that the data is consistent for the columns you wish to filter on.

---

Final edit to show something completely different from the original question:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, p.Unit, COUNT(od.Quantity) as TotalOrdered
  FROM Categories c INNER JOIN Products p ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
                    INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
                    INNER JOIN Order o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
                    INNER JOIN Customers cu ON o.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID
 WHERE cu.Country = 'Germany' and o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
 GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, p.Unit
 ORDER BY TotalOrdered DESC
 LIMIT 25;
```

> **Note:** This query will work on MySQL, MariaDB, and PostgreSQL. If you are using SQL Server, SQL Express, SQLite, Oracle, or some other database engine, you will need to adapt the syntax to match that system.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question:

You should first start with the object you want to get data about, in this case `Employees`:

```
SELECT LastName
FROM Employees -- Gets the LastName of every employee
```

Now we need a way to pull in `Orders` information, since you want "*the employee with the largest order quantity*". The way we associate an `Order` record with an `Employee` record is with a `JOIN` operator. In this case an `INNER JOIN` is sufficient because `INNER JOIN` returns rows only where there is a match between both tables. (This will filter out `Employees` who have no `Orders` which is what we want since you're looking for largest order quantity.)

```
SELECT Employees.LastName -- Specifying the Table name or using an Alias is good practice to avoid errors when the same column exists in two tables that are part of the same query (not the case here but it's best practice to do for readability too).
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Orders -- Returns a row for every Order for each Employee
    ON Employees.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId
```

Now we need to do the same thing to bring in the `OrderDetails` which is where your `Quantity` data lives. Again an `INNER JOIN` should be appropriate here, like so:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Orders -- Returns a row for every Order for each Employee
    ON Employees.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Returns a row for every OrderDetail of every Order. 
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
```

Notice my comments in the query. Since the first INNER JOIN of the query returns a row for every Order of each Employee, and the second INNER JOIN returns a row for every OrderDetail of every Order, this whole query now returns one row per OrderDetail of every Order for each Employee, so your row count will be Employees x Orders x OrderDetails essentially.

Now that we have all rows for *Employee Order Quantities* with the above query, we want to order the data by largest `Quantity` descending and then filter out everything but the first record. We can accomplish that with an `ORDER BY` clause and a `LIMIT` (`TOP` if you're using Microsoft SQL Server) like so:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Orders -- Returns a row for every Order for each Employee
    ON Employees.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Returns a row for every OrderDetail of every Order. 
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
ORDER BY OrderDetails.Quantity DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The final note here is more of a question on what your `OrderDetails` table represents (as a few other users have hinted at)? Is there always **only** one row in `OrderDetails` per `Order` like your example data shows or can have an `Order` relate to multiple rows in the `OrderDetails` table?

If an `Order` can relate to multiple `OrderDetails` then you need to do one more operation called a `GROUP BY` which will allow us to condense multiple `OrderDetail` rows that belong to the same `Order` per `Employee` and then aggregate their `Quantities` by summing them like so:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Orders -- Returns a row for every Order for each Employee
    ON Employees.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Returns a row for every OrderDetail of every Order. 
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
GROUP BY Employees.LastName, Orders.OrderID -- This condense the rows back down to just one row per Order per Employee. 
ORDER BY SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note the above gets you the `LastName` of the `Employee` who had the largest `Order` `Quantity` *on a single `Order`*. For example if EmployeeA has an Order with Quantity = 10 and EmployeeB has two different Orders, one with Quantity = 7 and the other with Quantity = 5, the above query will get you EmployeeA's `LastName`. But if you want to condense all `Quantities` between different `Orders` for the same `Employee` into one row to compare, such that in my previous example you'd want EmployeeB (because the sum of his two Orders' Quantities = 12 which is greater than 10 in EmployeeA's only Order) then you can *loosen* the `GROUP BY` clause to group on just the `Employee.LastName` field like so:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Orders -- Returns a row for every Order for each Employee
    ON Employees.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Returns a row for every OrderDetail of every Order. 
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
GROUP BY Employees.LastName -- This condense the rows down to just one row per Employee's LastName. 
ORDER BY SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

---

Now let's use what we learned above to answer your second question in the comments on "*What product was ordered the most by customers in Germany?*":

```
-- Gets the Product with the highest Quantity on a single OrderDetail
SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName -- The ID and Name of the Product
FROM Products -- Starting with what we want
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Getting the OrderDetails for each Product that was ordered
    ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.OrderID
INNER JOIN Orders -- Get the Order information for each OrderDetails so we can get the CustomerID
    ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN Customers -- Get the Customers so we can filter on only Customers from Germany
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Customers.Country = 'Germany' -- Filter out all records that don't have a Country = Germany
ORDER BY OrderDetails.Quantity DESC -- Order the rows by largest quantity first
LIMIT 1; -- Only return the top record by highest Quantity
```

Or:

```
-- Gets the Product with the highest Quantity on a single Order
SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName -- The ID and Name of the Product
FROM Products -- Starting with what we want
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Getting the OrderDetails for each Product that was ordered
    ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.OrderID
INNER JOIN Orders -- Get the Order information for each OrderDetails so we can get the CustomerID
    ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN Customers -- Get the Customers so we can filter on only Customers from Germany
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Customers.Country = 'Germany' -- Filter out all records that don't have a Country = Germany
GROUP BY Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName, Orders.OrderID -- Condenses all the OrderDetails rows to a single Order per Product and sums the Quantities for a total per Product per Order
ORDER BY SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) DESC -- Order the rows by largest quantity first
LIMIT 1; -- Only return the top record by highest Quantity
```

Or:

```
-- Gets the Product with the highest Quantity across all Orders
SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName -- The ID and Name of the Product
FROM Products -- Starting with what we want
INNER JOIN OrderDetails -- Getting the OrderDetails for each Product that was ordered
    ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.OrderID
INNER JOIN Orders -- Get the Order information for each OrderDetails so we can get the CustomerID
    ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN Customers -- Get the Customers so we can filter on only Customers from Germany
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Customers.Country = 'Germany' -- Filter out all records that don't have a Country = Germany
GROUP BY Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName -- Condenses all the OrderDetails and Orders rows to a single row per Product and sums the Quantities for a total per Product
ORDER BY SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) DESC -- Order the rows by largest quantity first
LIMIT 1; -- Only return the top record by highest Quantity
```